# Add value "001" to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add the value "006" to an MySql row, but it shows up as "6"! any fixes on my code ?

```
$id = "006";

mysql_query("INSERT INTO Table (id) VALUES ($id) ");
```

Thanks,

Comment: what is the field type?

Comment: make sure fieldtype is varchar(string)

Comment: tinytext, and the Collation is utf8_general_ci

Comment: @SomyA : I've tried that as well, it didn't work as well.

Comment: yeah, i think you forgot quotes on values, so it cast to an int.

Comment: @SomyA : how would I fix this, i really can't see the error.

Comment: the errors is missing single quotes on values. The values should be "VALUES ('$id')", not "VALUES ($id)"

Comment: @SomyA not if it's int type

Comment: OP: if one of the answers solved your problem, it would be awesome if you'd tick it

Comment: So there is a simple way to do this with when you create the table... just specify ZEROFILL see this post for more details.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845866/mysql-adding-leading-numbers-to-existing-ids-in-a-column

Answer (score 2):

If `id` is a numeric column such as an integer, `006` is the same as `6` so there isn't a way to explicitly save `006` since its exactly the same as `6`.

But if you want to retrieve that integer as a 3-digit, zero-padded string, you could use the `LPAD` function to pad it with `0`'s on the left side:

```
SELECT LPAD(id, 3, '0') as id FROM table;
```

Comment: So, how would i insert that value with the LPAD function ?

Comment: You would just continue using the same integer `id` column you have now, assuming your `id` column is currently an integer. You would just be _retrieving_ the data as a zero-padded string.

Comment: If this is the only solution, then i have to change tons of codes :(

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not a safe way:

```
$id = "006";

mysql_query("INSERT INTO Table (id) VALUES ('$id') ");
```

I think you forgot some quotes on values, so its cast to int.

Answer (score 0):

Your field needs to be a VARCHAR for that to work as you desire. You may also pad leading zeroes when you run your queries as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

1. I suppose that's just incorrect value (for the int field type) and cannot be stored at all.
2. Database intended to store **data**, means data without any additional formatting, which can be added at select time. That's how this thing works in general.

So, I'd suggest to store a regular int, and pad it with whatever number of zeros you wish at select time

Answer (score 0):

Try to use query in mysql.

`ALTER TABLE table MODIFY COLUMN id INT(3) ZEROFILL;`

this may solve your question.