# How to format that row to use same number of digits

Tags: mysql

I have a column named as ID in test table and it contains the data like `1,2,3`, I want to change it to `001,002,003`. How should I format that row to use same number of digits?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add value "001" to mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867958/add-value-001-to-mysql-database)

Comment: another possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845866/mysql-adding-leading-numbers-to-existing-ids-in-a-column

Comment: this is a duplicate. but if you want to update the table then follow the update syntax like so.. `UPDATE test_table t, 
(
    SELECT LPAD(id, 3, '0') as temp_id FROM test_table
) as temp 
SET t.id = temp.temp_id 
WHERE t.id = temp.id;`