# Not able to input string number into sql database using php

Tags: php, sql

I have the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['regKitsForm'])){

$kitsiteID = $_POST['kitsiteID'];

$sql = "SELECT patientID FROM patient WHERE patientNum=".$_POST['kitpatientID'];
$connect->execute($sql);
$get = $connect->fetch();
$kitpatientID = $get[0];


if(is_numeric($_POST['kitNum1'])) {

    $kitNum1 = str_pad($_POST['kitNum1'], 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

$kitForm = $_POST['kitForm'];


    $sql = "UPDATE form$kitForm SET v0".$kitForm."_dd_kitNum1=$kitNum1 WHERE patientID = $kitpatientID AND siteID = $kitsiteID";
```

This should be inputing e.g.: 00001 from $kitNum1, but it isn't... it's just inputing 1.

Please help

M

Comment: Well you are concatenating $kitForm, not $kitNum1 ?

Comment: `1` is a number, `00001` is not a number, it's a number with formatting applied making it a string

Comment: if you had your column in the database as integer it will always put 1 nstead of 00001 make it varchar(5) and it will work. **PS you can change 5 by your own size**

Comment: Is there any way to force the sql to input it as string and not number?

Comment: Type cast to string: `(string) $kitNum1`

Comment: The column is already varchar(5) ;_;

Comment: May this post will help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200754/mysql-how-to-front-pad-zip-code-with-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure, that your database column is of a string type like `varchar(5)` and not of an integer type. In addition, put quotes around the value in your query so that it isn't interpreted as a number, but as a string instead:

```
$sql = "UPDATE form$kitForm SET v0".$kitForm."_dd_kitNum1='$kitNum1' WHERE patientID = $kitpatientID AND siteID = $kitsiteID";
```

Comment: column was already varchar(5), but the quotes solved it. THANKS! :)