# How to insert all the permutations of xxxxx number in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, permutation

I have a table called "numbers"

id (int, auto-increment)

number (varchar)

How can I insert all permutations of a number contating 5 digits [0-9] ?

00000
00001
00002
...
99999

Comment: Use LPAD function: `LPAD(125, 5, '0');` Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200754/mysql-how-to-front-pad-zip-code-with-0)

Comment: @DennisY.Parygin that's cool, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a select statement generating numbers from `0` to `99999` including `0` left padding. Then you can use this with `INSERT` statement to insert them where you want in a single shot.

```
SELECT LPAD(F.t*10000+E.num3,5,'0') num FROM
(
    SELECT 100*num1+num2 num3
    FROM (
    SELECT t*10+u num1
    FROM
        (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) A,
        (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) B
    ) C,
    (
    SELECT t*10+u num2
    FROM
        (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) A,
        (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) B
    ) D
) E,
(SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) F

ORDER BY num
```

Output is:

```
+-------+
|  num  |
+-------+
| 00000 |
| 00001 |
| 00002 |
| ...   |
| 99999 |
+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

`LPAD(str,len,padstr)` - Returns the string str, left-padded with the string padstr to a length of len characters. If str is longer than len, the return value is shortened to len characters.

```
mysql> SELECT LPAD('hi',4,'??');
        -> '??hi'
mysql> SELECT LPAD(123, 5,'0');
        -> 00123
```

MySQL Documentation. 12.5 String Functions. [function LPAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)