# How to add zero before int in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have Mysql table which include zip code and it is int.

The problem is when I insert a zip code begin with 0 " 0123" it saves like "123" without zero.

How to solve it in mysql structure ?

regards

Comment: use `varchar` instead of `int`

Comment: you can change data type to `varchar`, `char` or `text`

Comment: change data type to `unsigned-zerofill`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200754/mysql-how-to-front-pad-zip-code-with-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't store the zip codes as int.

Storing the zip-codes as varchar(10) or something like that will keep your zero padding and also cater for alphanumeric zip codes which may be used in some areas.

Answer (score 5):

You could change your `zip_code` field data type to something like `varchar`:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name VARCHAR(6);
```

Or if you prefer to keep it as an integer and fill it with leading zeros you can use `ZEROFILL`:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name INT(6) ZEROFILL;
```

e.g. `123` becomes `000123`, `1234` becomes `001234` etc.. (depends on length)