# How to generate id number like 'xxx0000', 'xxx0001'?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my table :

```
|   ID    |
| xxx0000 |
| xxx0001 |
| xxx0002 |
```

i want to make my id pattern like that, but i dont know how to generate it?

Comment: If you want this to be auto-incrementing in the database then I would suggest that you make the `ID` column a normal auto-increment field and have a separate field for whatever you're adding to it.  Then perform the concatenation/formatting in a view or query.  Basically, there's no rule that says the underlying data must exactly match the resulting display of that data.  In many cases the two should be different for very good reasons.  In this case you have a single display element which is composed of two different data elements.

Comment: @David thump up, for more chars and words in a comment as in the question :-)

Comment: $id = "xxx".substr("0000".$i,-4);

Comment: @David if you say so, can you make an example for me? I cant understand any further without an example. Btw 'xxx' is the date and month of birth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two different pieces of data, so make two different columns.

```
ID              INT            NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT,
SomethingElse   SomeOtherType  NOT NULL
```

What `SomethingElse` is named and what data type it is would be up to you.  `xxx` doesn't tell us much.

If both of these things combined make up your primary key, you can use a composite key of multiple columns:

```
PRIMARY KEY (SomethingElse, ID)
```

The same integrity checks for any primary key will continue to apply, the database will simply check both columns for combined uniqueness.

At this point you have the *data* you want, now it's just a matter of *displaying* it how you want.  Whether you do that in SQL or in PHP is up to you.  Whether you want the application to see them as a single value or see the underlying different values, also up to you.

Selecting them as a single value from SQL could be simple enough.  Something like:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SomethingElse, ID) AS ID FROM ...
```

If you always want those padded zeroes then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200754/mysql-how-to-front-pad-zip-code-with-0) will help.  Other string manipulations you might want to do would also be tackled one at a time (and each could result in its own Stack Overflow question if you need assistance with it).

But the basic idea here is that what you have is a *composite* value.  In a relational database you would generally store the *underlying* values and perform the composition when querying the data.