# SQL how to add a leading 0

Tags: mysql

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. Im quite new to mySQL and figured there has to be an easier way to update my database.

So my issue is that I have a number of records that don't have a leading zero but I need the total number of characters in any record to be 5.

e.g. 6930 should in fact be 06930

I came across this code but I am unable to get it to work correctly, could anyone point me in the right direction.

```
 UPDATE `it_asset_register`.`tab_id_master` 
 SET tab_id_master.ID = LEFT('00000', 5-LEN(tab_id_master.ID)) +    tab_id_master.ID
 WHERE ID = '8407' AND LEN(tab_id_master.ID)<5 AND Len(tab_id_master.ID)>0;
```

Thanks

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200754/mysql-how-to-front-pad-zip-code-with-0 (LPAD function).
Also change your column to ZEROFILL (like INT(11) ZEROFILL)

Comment: Use `LPAD` function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a leading zero to some values in column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165104/adding-a-leading-zero-to-some-values-in-column-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**LPAD** should do the job here:

```
SELECT LPAD ('123', 5, '0');
00123

SELECT LPAD ('12345', 5, '0');
12345
```

Try:

```
UPDATE `it_asset_register`.`tab_id_master` 
 SET tab_id_master.ID = LPAD (tab_id_master.ID, 5, '0')
 WHERE ID = '8407' AND LENGTH(tab_id_master.ID)<5 AND LENGTH(tab_id_master.ID)>0;
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I am getting an error message that function LEN doesn't exist

Comment: this does exactly what I am looking for, thank you so much... if I remove the ID = '8407' will this apply to all fields? just double checking before I run it.

Comment: To see which rows will be affected, put the WHERE clause into a SELECT statement; e.g.:

`SELECT * FROM ``it_asset_register``.``tab_id_master`` 
     WHERE ID = '8407' AND LENGTH(tab_id_master.ID)<5 AND LENGTH(tab_id_master.ID)>0;`

You may then remove the `ID = '8407' AND` part without affecting any data, prior to actually performing the UPDATE.

Comment: I just ran this and discovered there are a lot more records than I would have thought like this, but when I amended the code to `UPDATE `it_asset_register`.`tab_id_master` SET tab_id_master.ID = LPAD (tab_id_master.ID, 5, '0') WHERE LENGTH(tab_id_master.ID)<5 AND LENGTH(tab_id_master.ID)>0; ` I keep getting an error message of 1175 in relation to a key column but the ID field I'm using is the Primary Key column.. would it be safe enough to disable safe update?

Comment: I think that's probably worth a new question.

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate two or more strings in MySQL, you must use the `CONCAT()` function.
A possible solution can be:

```
UPDATE tab_id_master
SET id = SUBSTRING(CONCAT('00000', id), -5)
WHERE LENGTH(id) > 0 AND LENGTH(id) < 5;
```

Alternatively you can use the `LPAD()` function:

```
UPDATE tab_id_master
SET id = LPAD(id, 5, '0')
WHERE LENGTH(id) > 0 AND LENGTH(id) < 5;
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
    table_name
SET
    column_name = RIGHT('00000' + CAST(column_name AS CHAR), 5)
```

This concatenates the 5 zeros and your ID to something like '000001234'. Then it selects the 5 rightmost characters.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify `tab_id_master.ID` type. If it is of a numeric type you wouldn't be able to store a number with leading zeros but otherwise you could use `LPAD()`:

```
SET tab_id_master.ID = LPAD(tab_id_master.ID, 5, 0)
```