# How to set field to zerofill after create table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax, zerofill

I created the table with `stud_id int, phone_number int`, So after that I want to add some settings like zerofill in `phone_number`. So how can I set this zerofill?

I saw in the internet `alter table table_name`
But there were : 1)change table name, 2) drop table, 3) rename table 4)rename column in table etc.
I know that when we are creating the table, we can set all config like : `auto_increment`, `primary key()` etc. But I want to set after creating.

```
create table student(stud_id int, phone_number int);
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3201014/2469308 (in the Duplicate marked question)

Comment: answer is ```alter table student change `phone_number` `phone_number` int (10) unsigned zerofill not null;```