# laravel 5.7 eloquent save digits as string

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.7.

I have a field on database set as below

```
$table->string('last_no', 5)
```

and I want to save the "last_no" will save digits as string. just like

```
Model::create( [ "last_no" => "00351"] );
```

but I don't know why it will save "351" to DB not "00351".

I have already try set as below but still have this issue.

```
protected $casts = [
    'last_no' => "string"
];
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: try my answer..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200754/mysql-how-to-front-pad-zip-code-with-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with `sprintf()`

```php
$last_no=sprintf('%05d',351);
Model::create( [ "last_no" => $last_no] );
```