# Laravel validation of numeric value with leading space passes validation and fails database insert

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-validation

I have the following validation:

`'location.zip_code' => ['required', 'numeric', 'max:99999'],`

It's working as expected except if I submit my form with a numeric value preceeded by a space, like  `12345`. A trailing space gets trimmed via the `TrimStrings` middleware (presumably), but a leading space doesn't?

This ends up causing this error:

`SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'zip_code' at row 1`

I know I can change my save method to do something like, `$validatedData = $this->validate();` and then handle each form input value, trimming this one in the process, but I've got a lot going on in the form, and it would be great if there was a way for this to just work the way it should work. Hoping someone has an idea.

Comment: is your `zip_code` field in the database an integer or a string ? if you switch it to integer, you wouldn't have to care about leading space in a numeric field.

Comment: Why presumably? `TrimString` does `preg_replace('~^[\s​]+|[\s​]+$~u', '', $value) ?? trim($value)`, no need for assumptions, it [removes leading and trailing spaces](https://onlinephp.io/c/e5edb).

Comment: well, because it's seemingly not removing the leading space, hence what prompted the question. Evidently I've done something that's caused TrimString not to work as I would expect it to work.

Comment: Can you add a `dd` and show us the result wih the space?

Comment: I could change the zip code to be numeric, yes, but I'd also like to understand why a leading space isn't trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct approach is to modify the `zip_code` field in my database to be an integer left padded to 5 digits to account for zip codes that start with 0.
Similar to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3201014/4113027